GA4 User Acquisition Report not recording anything after certain date
My traffic acquisition report shows that people are finding my website through organic.

But when I check user acquisition report it shows a big gap in traffic after May15:

It shows 20+ organic traffic on the last day but it never records it.

Any idea what happened?
I made sure that the tracking codes are on the site.  Could it be because I have both GA4 and GTM codes running on the site that one of the tracking codes is stopping the data from being recorded?

Were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Yes I did figure it out.  It was the user-provided data collection.  I had to turn it off.  It might be different for you. But now it is recording data again.
